# Trouble starting a PhoneStateListener from an ON_BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I am trying to restart a PhoneStateListener after the phone has been rebooted (if my isRunning SharedPref is true... i.e. the listener was running before the reboot)

Here is my code...

Eclipse gives me an error on the line: final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(srvcName);

It says that getSystemService(String) is not defined. Anyone know why? The same basic code works just fine in my main app activity.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    String srvcName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
    final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(srvcName); 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0); 
        if(getRunning()){
             telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
        }

      }
```

Comment: What does the logcat say at that time ? Also, can you try moving the getSystemService call in the onRecieve method

Comment: there's no logcat, it won't compile. Also, moving the getSystemService call into onReceive doesn't help... same error message in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it won't compile because `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Context`.

Second, a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` cannot register a listener. That `BroadcastReceiver` object, and likely its whole process, will go away milliseconds after `onReceive()` completes.

Please listen for the `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast, which gives you the same information as a `PhoneStateListener`. As an added bonus, you will not need to get control at boot time, which saves you a permission and speeds up reboots on your users' phones.